# How to implement POST-GET-REDIRECT when RequestMapping is placed in top of the class?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, request-mapping

I have RequestMapping annotation placed in the class level:

```
@RequestMapping("view")
public class MyClas {...}
```

I have my method annotated with renderMapping:

```
@RenderMapping(params = "portletAction=myAction")
public String MyAction(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse response, @ModelAttribute Bean bean, BindingResult result,
        Model model) {...}
```

The problem is that after calling `myAction()` and `returning to home page`, 
when pressing `F5`, this method is `called` again, 
so I thought to implement the `Post/Redirect/Get` pattern, 
but all the solutions I found in `stackoverflow` where related to modifying the `RequestMapping`, 
that I can not do, since it is in `class` level, and the `class` has a lot of other `methods`.

*Does anyone have any idea what to do in this case?*

Comment: How do you expect it to work? You'll need to put the annotation telling Spring where to go on top of the appropriate method. You can specify something like this:  `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = 'action=someAction')` You don't have to change the view name.

Comment: Please read the question better, it works fine. I am requesting something else

Comment: requestMapping is placed at the class level ;)

Comment: So why can't you annotate it again? I'm missing that part.

Comment: You mean putting "@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = 'action=someAction')" in the place of renderMapping?

Comment: This way there will be one requestMapping annotation at class level, and one at method level, is this normal ?

Comment: You aren't limited to a single use of @RequestMapping, and value='' is optional. Your class level annotation specifies the view, whereas you can specify GET/POST requests on each method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109457/discussion-between-albano-vito-and-christopher-schneider).